# Is there a more-accurate indicator of an app download's progress than what appears in Launchpad?

Tags: mac-appstore, command-line, launchpad

While downloading an application from the Mac App Store, you are presented with a progress indicator in Launchpad, like so:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode 4.3 installing]

For a large install (like Xcode, as shown) this doesn't provide a terribly useful picture of the download's performance (how fast it's going / how much longer it's likely to take).

Is there any way (perhaps via a command-line tool) to get a more-accurate look at the progress of an App Store download? Something more along the lines of, say, `585,789 Kb / 1,768,231 Kb Downloaded`?

Comment: Doesn't it show that in the App Store app? With percentage and time remaining?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you are in the App store, click on the "Purchases" button on the top bar. This will give you the total size of the app as well as how much has been downloaded. I think it even gives you an estimated time frame until completion.

Comment: You're right, of course - I'd somehow forgotten that tab existed! Feels good to finally have Xcode installed in there, instead of the Xcode Installer entry constantly offering to let me re-download it... My OCD is soothed. :)